# Terraform Multiple Repository With Workspaces or Modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to the terraform and I am confused about workspaces and modules. The thing I am trying to do is have multiple accounts called network-account, production-account, and log-account. The problem is; I want to have a directory structure for every account like

```
-root
|- production-account
|  |-- main.tf
|  |--  vars.tf
|- network-account
|  |-- main.tf
|  |--  vars.tf
|- log-account
|  |-- main.tf
|  |--  vars.tf
```

and some resources have reference to another resources. How can I do that without doing `terraform init` for each repository? And also I want to have different state files, is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, create a main.tf and vars.tf under root directory and call account directories from there, By doing this, you can reference one directory (or module) to another and your structure will be more combined.

Comment: I forgot something, sorry. Is it possible to do that with different state files with this structure?

Comment: Are each of these accounts running identical infrastructure, or different infrastructure?

Comment: They are running different infrastructures and some of the resources have to refer to others.